# How do I add a rich document content text view the on-load window of a MacOS app for Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, document

I'm trying to add a Rich Document Content Text View to the on-load window of a basic text editing macOS app, but I can't figure out how. Is there a certain code I have to add? Because I don't see anywhere I can put it on the `Main.storyboard`.

Here's all I see:

[image: The Upper Bar]

I just need to know how to add a field for it.

Comment: How is the Xcode project created, which options did you choose?